# MacBook Pro freezes 4 or 5 times a day with no info in the Console

Tags: performance, macos

My mid-2011 MBP (Core i7, Lion), seems to fart around 4 or 5 times a day. It usually happens randomly. There doesn't seem to be any issues in Console before the "boot" line.

What happens is that computer stops responding, including mouse, lights, function keys, etc. The only thing to do is to turn it off manually and back on again.

**EDIT DEC 1, 2011** for the last 3 weeks I haven't had a single freeze. It all happened after I updated my OS X.

Comment: I have had issues with OS X locking up when I have an NTFS volume present (meaning you have Windows installed via bootcamp).  I resolved this issue by telling OS X not to auto mount the NTFS partition.

Comment: I have the exact same issue as you describe it. Strangely enough i can boot and run my second partition, which is a linux one, without having the freezing issue after all. (Runs for more than a year now, without freezing up). After all it is a hardware issue i suppose, even if in my case it seems different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly some kind of hardware problem. It could very well be your hard drive, as @M123 suggests. It could also be memory or even something wrong on the logic board. It's hard to narrow down without further tests, but with mouse and *everything* freezing, it's almost certain a low-level lock up.

What is your situation for bringing it to an Apple store or getting some diagnostic tools?

Comment: I have a business trip next week. I'll take it to the apple supplier in two weeks. It's covered until may

Comment: At the very least, it would be useful to have Apple (or whomever) run a series of diagnostics, even memory tests.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive could be failing. Download SMART utility to check.

Comment: I ran a SMART analysis with no errors

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent backup, I would say an erase and install can verify if it is something wrong with your hard drive, or if it is a software issue.